# Grails - Refreshing object list using checkbox?

Tags: grails, checkbox

So I'm diving into Grails for the first time and am trying to accomplish what I think would be an easy task, so I hope this is trivial. Time spent on it is making me feel otherwise :)

So I have a list of Contacts in a database that are tied to a boolean called isActive. I want to have a check box in my list gsp that determines whether to show inactive members or not.

I've tried using a Javascript function (which I could successfully call, but wasn't sure how to handle the passing after the call). I've also tried to add a g:if to check to see if the box's checked property was enabled, but this results in a null object (which I suspected would happen).

I've also tried attaching a remoteFunction call on the onclick of the checkbox, but I never get a response back unfortunately.

Any advice? Thanks - I appreciate it. The challenges of teaching yourself a web language for the first time :)

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'contact.label', default: 'Contact')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>

    <g:javascript>
        function updateThisPage()
        {

        }
    </g:javascript>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="#list-contact" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
            <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            <li><g:checkBox name="showInactives" value="${false}" onclick="....." /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="list-contact" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <g:if test="${isActive?.checked}">
                    <g:sortableColumn property="firstName" title="${message(code: 'contact.firstName.label', default: 'First Name')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="lastName" title="${message(code: 'contact.lastName.label', default: 'Last Name')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="phone" title="${message(code: 'contact.phone.label', default: 'Phone')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="email" title="${message(code: 'contact.email.label', default: 'Email')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="title" title="${message(code: 'contact.title.label', default: 'Title')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="jobFunc" title="${message(code: 'contact.jobFunc.label', default: 'Job Func')}" />
                </g:if>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${contactInstanceList}" status="i" var="contactInstance">
                            <g:if test="${contactInstance.isActive}">
                                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${contactInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: contactInstance, field: "firstName")}</g:link></td>

                                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: contactInstance, field: "lastName")}</td>

                                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: contactInstance, field: "phone")}</td>

                                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: contactInstance, field: "email")}</td>

                                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: contactInstance, field: "title")}</td>

                                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: contactInstance, field: "jobFunc")}</td>

                                </tr>
                            </g:if>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate total="${contactInstanceTotal}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try JQuery & CSS combination? For example, with every  field you have, add a class "Active" or "Inactive" according to their record in Database. Then when you click the button, simply add the class "Hidden" for all the elements that have "Inactive" class.

```
jQuery("#hideInactiveContact").click(function(){
   jQuery(".Inactive").addClass("Hidden");
});

jQuery("#showInactiveContact").click(function(){
   jQuery(".Inactive").removeClass("Hidden");
});
```

In CSS, you can do the following and all the elements of "Hidden" class will be hid:

```
.Hidden {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Let me give this a shot. Keep you posted - Thank you sincerely for your input!